Can I say "let's eat. Hurry up!" to just one person while I am not eating or about to eat?
I know "let's" is short for "let us". For example,
Let's break for lunch. = Let us break for lunch.
But Oxford dictionary  says "let’s [no passive] used for making suggestions or as a polite way of telling people what you want them to do"
Can I use "let's do something" when we want only one person to do something?
Say I have finished my dinner already but my daughter has not touched her dinner yet because she was playing while I was eating.
Can I say "let's eat! Lana! Hurry up!" (Lana is her name)?

Which Oxford Dictionary? I can't find that definition online. It doesn't sound natural to me to use "Let's eat" to encourage a child to eat.

I could see that used specifically when talking to a child, or as a very patronizing way to encourage someone - "come on, Maggie, let's brush our teeth, shall we?". But it's a rather non-standard use - let's generally implies doing something together or by both yourself and someone, even if your actual involvement is rather metaphorical (eg. a manager telling the team "Let's get this released tomorrow", in the sense of "I want you to release that tomorrow").

"Let's eat! Lana! Hurry up! We can't be late getting to  your grandmother's house." It's fine. You can always trust that dictionary. Frankly, you can say whatever you like to your daughter. Would  you say that in Vietnamese?//Let's eat, Lana. Aren't you hungry? Of course, one or more persons.

It's rather patronising, but it's sometimes done as a behaviour management device, avoid conflict by stating what "we" do, instead of telling what "you" must do.

It's a relatively "affected, patronising" usage if Let's [verb] is functioning as an "imperative" - speaker urging / cajoling addressee to [verb] in contexts where the speaker doesn't participate in [verbing]. Reminiscent of matron doing the ward rounds and asking patients How are we today? Best avoided, imho.

@KateBunting, I use https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/let_1?q=let

Ah - I did check Oxford Learners' , but I looked up let's rather than let. I think it would be more natural to say something like "Let's hurry up and finish our dinner", because "Let's eat" is normally a suggestion to a companion to stop what you are doing for a meal.

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2332756/ Mothers' use of we [Let's]  in social--vocal interchange, indicating a system for establishing a shared relationship with the child, was closely connected with their verbal responsiveness to their children. The total amount of maternal talking, the number of personal pronouns used by mothers, and their verbal responsiveness to their children were not related to mothers' social class or years of education

The proposed sentence suggests to me that Lana is in a high chair and the speaker is about to wield the spoon. I wouldn't use it except to a young child.

@Tom In your example, if you have eaten and still saying, Let's eat Lana"' it means Lana is a small child and you are going to spoon feed her. Only small kids need to be cajoled to eat their lunch.

Would you say We should [Let's]  finish our food in Vietnamese to only refer to yourself??

We sometimes use "us" when giving commands to "soften" them. By including yourself in those being told what to do, it sounds less like an order and more like a suggestion or idea.
So yes, arguably in this case the technically grammatically correct thing to say would be, "Eat!" or "You have to eat now".
Similarly, a boss telling implies not to be late for work might say, "We have to all start getting here by 9:00." Even if he himself has never been late, and as the boss he could probably get away with being late, he says "we" instead of "you" to make it less harsh.

The Oxford Dictionary says "let’s [no passive] used for making suggestions or as a polite way of telling people what you want them to do"
Right, so whenever you make a suggestion or want to be polite, you can use it. Usually, with an active verb.
Let's eat.
Let's leave.
Let's shop.
Let's stop. etc, etc, etc.

Listen, Kenny, let's eat before they let us out of jail because we have no money!
[in court] Counsel, let's adjourn until tomorrow so we can examine the new evidence.

If the father has finished eating and says:
"Let's eat! Lana! Hurry up! We can't be late getting to your grandmother's house."
Refer to the definition above. It's common for a parent to use we with children.

Both of your examples involve both the speaker and someone else following the suggestion (let us (both) eat, let us (all) adjourn). The OP is asking about cases where the speaker does not intend to follow the suggestion (telling someone "let's eat" when you've already finished and want just them to eat).

@MaciejStachowski "Let's eat! Lana! Hurry up! We can't be late getting to your grandmother's house." Sure, a parent could use the plural Let's. Even if the father has finished.

@MaciejStachowski Nothing in the definition suggests it has to be more than one person: "let’s [no passive] used for making suggestions or as a polite way of telling people [or one person] what you want them to do per se.

Thing is, the OLD usage examples don't really match that definition, and other dictionaries disagree (Collins, Cambridge and others spell out explicitly "suggestion... that includes you and the other person or people"). I really don't think it's standard usage - if you tell me Let's go to the store!, I'm going to assume you're going too, not that you're just suggesting that I go.

@MaciejStachowski Parents often use we to speak to a child. Just like a man might say about his wife: We are pregnant. Same idea.

Mothers' use of we in social--vocal interchange, indicating a system for establishing a shared relationship with the child, was closely connected with their verbal responsiveness to their children. The total amount of maternal talking, the number of personal pronouns used by mothers, and their verbal responsiveness to their children were not related to mothers' social class or years of education. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2332756/

And Kate Bunting agrees that parents use we, See under comments above.

I've noted the usage towards children myself in the comments above, but this does not really extend to general use the way OP's question title would suggest. You should probably clarify that in the answer - as it stands, it reads to me that the use of let's in any situation to make a suggestion towards only the other person is fine.

@MaciejStachowski The OP is specifically talking about his young daughter, something he often does. It obviously has to refer to two people. You can't just use it to refer to yourself. AND I already showed the kid thing. So, I'm satisfied.
